# How do you find the value of a and b?

Tags: calculus, functions

\begin{equation}
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
\frac{\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt{x}}{a} & , \text { if } & x>0 \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}(x+b) & , \text { if } & x \leq 0
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

How do you find the value of a and b such that the function is continuous and differentiable?
It is found that $b=1$ is necessary for $f$ to be continuous at $x=0$, but when I tried to find the value of $a$ so that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$, I cannot eliminate $x$.
Can anyone help me solve this question?

Comment: I don't think that you can solve this problem because $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f^{\prime}(x)=-\infty$.

Comment: @garondal It is irrelevant that $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f'(x) = -\infty$. You have to show that the left derivative $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \dfrac{f(x) - f0)}{x - 0} $ of $f$ at $0$ does not agree with the right derivative at $0$ which is $1/\sqrt a$. And in fact the left derivative is $-\infty$.